# How to adjust individual attributes of PairGrid plots?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I am using PairGrid in Seaborn with sns.distplots in the diagonal.

How can I set a different number of bins for each of the histograms in the diagonal?

I can't find the answer to this question anywhere and I can't simply set bins to a list of number of bins because it takes that as the bin edges for all histograms in the diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to pass differing arguments to PairGrid. However, you can rely on the fact that the grid is filled consecutively in the order of the dataframe columns. Hence using an iterator over the desired number of bins (or any other parameter) would allow for different parameters per subplot on the diagonal.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)

nbins = iter([3,7,13,24])
def myhist(*args, **kwargs):
    plt.hist(*args, bins=next(nbins), edgecolor="k", **kwargs)

g.map_diag(myhist)
g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]